# replace() for translating color names

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some code to translate some color names, and this is what I did, quick and dirty.
But I'm guessing there might be some function to replace arrays with arrays maybe, like in PHP, where you can have `str_replace($array_of_colors, $replace_array_of_colors, $colors);`.

```
var color = colors[c].replace(/sort/i, "Black");
color = color.replace(/brun/i, "Brown");
color = color.replace(/hvit/i, "White");
color = color.replace(/oransje/i, "Orange");
color = color.replace(/gul/i, "Yellow");
color = color.replace(/beige/i, "Beige");
color = color.replace(/Mørk/i, "Dark");
color = color.replace(/Rosa/i, "Pink");
color = color.replace(/rød/i, "Red");
color = color.replace(/Blå/i, "Blue");
color = color.replace(/grå/i, "Gray");
color = color.replace(/Lys/i, "Light");
color = color.replace(/lilla/i, "Purple");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're mixing up data and logic. Separate your replaces into an associative array and iterate over that instead: (My JS is extremely bad, so this will be more pseudocode-ish)

```
var associations;
associations['/brun/i'] = "Brown";
associations['/sort/i'] = "Black";
//add all the other associations and then

associations.forEach(runReplace);

function runReplace(value, regex, array) {
   color.replace(regex, value);
}
```

Additionally I suggest you (just like me here) use the [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) when iterating over your `colors`

Answer (score 10):

Maintenance is key. Anything that might change in the future is the mapping of the keys to the translated color names. So let´s keep that part as simple as possible with a simple key/value mapping:

```
var colors = {
  sort: 'Black',
  brun: 'Brown',
  hvit: 'White'
};
```

Instead of checking for each key individually, let´s create one regular expression that includes every key. `Object.keys()` returns the keys of an object as an array. `Array.prototype.join(val)` concatenates every element of an array with `val`. The pipe `|` signals an `or` in a regular expression. Do not forget to set the flags `g` for multiple occurences of the same key in the text as well as the `i` to ignore case sensitivity.

```
var regExp = new RegExp("(" + Object.keys(colors).join('|') + ')', 'gi');
```

The second parameter of `String.prototype.replace()` must not be a string, but can also be a function to replace strings dynamically. The first parameter of `dynamicReplace` is the part of the regex that actually matched. The second parameter `key` is the part that matched the string we put in parentheses `(` `)` within our regular expression. In this example `match` and `key` result in the same string, but this might not be the case for more complex regular expressions. `dynamicReplace` uses the mapping as a lookup table to return the translated color.

```
var text = 'My sort cat is brun!';
console.log(text.replace(regExp, function dynamicReplace(match, key) {
  return colors[key];
}));

// => My Black cat is Brown!
```

Comment: I would add that subjecting the result of a substitution to further substitution can be a source of bugs — it just happens not to be a problem in this case. Note that in the general case, you have to [watch out for special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1157100) when constructing the regex.

Comment: @200_success: I do not understand your first statement tbh. `var colors = { a: 'b', b: 'c' }` and `var text = 'ab'` still result in `text === 'bc'`. So further substitutions are not applied to the result of previous one. Or what do you mean?